# Why CNN Linear Regression predicting always same value?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn, linear-regression

I have dataset with around 3 million samples which almost fit to gauss distribution. X-axis are
normalized target values.
[image]

I am using WRN model and if i am solving binary or multi-class classification problem everything works as expected, but if i replace output layer with regression layer with linear activation i will end up with model predicting always same value very close to 0.5

So it seems my model is no better than model which is averaging target values. I was expecting very narrow range of predicted values, but not falling always to the same value. How is it even possible when i am giving model more information than splitting dataset into 2 or 3 classes? Does it mean my model is not complex enough to learn anything? How should I proceed in such situation?

Btw my loss function for linear regression is mean squared error.

Comment: Code would be required

Comment: @Peter [link](https://code.labstack.com/YHrPWFS3) to WRN model

Comment: @Peter [link](https://code.labstack.com/DC8lvsJf) to training script